# Get bitrate from remote video (pure nodejs)

Tags: node.js

I have videos in s3 and am curious if there is a way the bitrate can be efficiently gained using nodejs. I'm looking to make the new lambda Aws service run against newly added s3 objects to get bitrate.

Since I need to run in just node I can't use ffmpeg here

Comment: hey, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ListenerApproved/node-ffprobe

just did this on my node server, use probeData.format.bit_rate

Comment: Perhaps you may want to provide an example?

Comment: this won't work because there is no way to install ffmpeg on lambda